# 80s/90s book about a child looking for a member of an alien race, who would teach him to play a flute-like instrument

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

Seeking the title of a book I read a part of from an elementary school reader. In it, a young boy runs away from home to seek out a teacher to learn to play music. The teacher would be from an alien race that the colonists haven’t seen in a long time. The city he went to was mostly water. And I think the instrument was similar to a flute. The school reader would have been from the 1980s or 90s.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 4):

[Sweetwater](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/504200.Sweetwater) by Laurence Yep

> On the planet Harmony, Tyree and his people are fighting to survive.
>   Their beautiful world holds terrible dangers -- vicious sea creatures,
>   diminishing food supplies, and, at the heart of it all, a rising tide
>   that will soon destroy the city where they cling to their way of life.
>
> Tyree has secretly befriended Amadeus, the greatest songmaster of the
>   native alien race. Amadeus teaches Tyree about the power of music,
>   and, to Tyree's blind sister, he gives an awesome treasure. But his
>   gift kindles the fears of Tyree's people -- fears more dangerous than
>   the sea itself. Tyree must help his people before they tear their
>   community apart.
>
> In this richly inventive science-fiction novel, acclaimed children's
>   author Laurence Yep creates a future world that is as haunting and as
>   powerful as the song that Tyree learns to play.

Comment: Thank you, that’s the book! I’ve been trying to find it for years